# Combining SQL Where Clauses

Tags: sql

This is my code

```
SELECT sum(qty) as "sumqty", shipdate, groupnumber
from test
where (shipdate = #5/30/2014# and groupnumber = "A30") OR ( shipdate #5/31/2014# and groupnumber ="A31")
group by shipdate, groupnumber
order by sum(qty) desc;
```

Is there a way to shorten the where clause? Because I want to add more shipdate and groupnumber combinations.

Comment: Your `where` clause seems quite reasonable.

Comment: If those are the conditions you are looking for then about the only suggestion I have would be to parametrize the query for reuse.  But the where clause is fine unless there is something specific you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Which database server are you using, and which version of it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your question isn't about your current query, but about scaling the query to include more combinations of `shipdate` and `groupnumber`. Obviously, if you only have a few more such combinations to add, then it's not a big deal to just add them. However, if you need to add *many* more such combinations, then consider using a join.

You haven't said which database server and version you're using, so I'll have to try to be general.

1. Create a temporary table with `shipdate` and `groupnumber` columns
2. Use a `WHERE EXISTS` clause:

   ```
   SELECT sum(qty) as "sumqty", shipdate, groupnumber
   from test
   where exists (
       select shipdate,groupnumber
       from #Temp_Table as tt
       where tt.shipdate = test.shipdate and tt.groupnumber = test.groupnumber)
   group by shipdate, groupnumber
   order by sum(qty) desc;
   ```

Comment: The shortening of the query has been reached here at the cost of partial replacement of the query length to DML statement for population of the temporary table.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all occurrences of "test." prefix because there is a single table in the query.
You can use short alias names of selected fields.

Comment: None of your suggestions would make the query shorter or more efficient.

Comment: I disagree with removing the prefix - point 1 above.  It is best practice to prefix all column references with the table alias, even in simple queries.

Comment: Comment of PM 77-1: the question was to make the query shorter, not to make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does anyone know how to make it shorter?

Comment: Answer for comment from Michael Green: free cheese is only in mice trap. Or if you want to win something you must pay for it.

Comment: Judging by the question as edited, the OP's meaning of "shorten" does not include trivial syntax edits.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a stored procedure, and then pass the different shipdates and group numbers into that, the query would then become

`SELECT sum(qty) as "sumqty", shipdate, groupnumber
from test
where (shipdate = @ShipDate and groupnumber = @GroupNumber) 
group by shipdate, groupnumber
order by sum(qty) desc;`

If you need to get a result set for multiple sets of ShipDate/GroupNumber combinations you can just UNION or UNION ALL the results, depending on your requirements.

Please note this is not the only way of solving this problem, if you find that you need to query for lots of combinations a common table expression or even dynamic SQL might perform better